# batch script to print one level up directory name - what is the issue in the code

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I am trying to write a batch script to print the name of the directory that is one level up from where the batch file is, but I am running into issues.

```batch-file
@echo off
set current_dir=%cd%    
set parent_dir=%current_dir%\.. 
echo %parent_dir%
pause
```

The output is the current directory name followed by `\..`. For example - `C:\dev\..`

Comment: @Compo - Thank you for your response. I don't understand batch scripting, and I thought `\..` is the right command, but I just realized that I am probably looking for `..`, cause that is what I see happening in cmd.

Comment: @Compo - so can I not, append two dots after the `cd`, like how I am able to do in `cmd`?

Comment: Thank you @Compo. May I ask why I can not use `cd` in the batch file, just for curious reasons.

Comment: could you put your comment as an answer so others could benefit in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to be aware of, is that the Current Directory, (`%CD%\.`, `%__CD__%.`), and the directory holding the running script, (`%~dp0.`), are two completely different things. The majority of times, those two things would only match, if you have specifically `Set` them to do so, or you don't change working directory and run the batch file with GUI mouse clicks, *(not recommended)*.

Your script shows the term 'parent' for the wanted directory, when in fact the body text implies you need the parent of the parent directory, *(let's call that the grandparent)*.

To get the parent directory of the batch file defined as an absolute path, you'd use:

```bash
@For %%G In ("%~dp0.") Do @Set "Parent=%%~fG"
@Echo %Parent%
@Pause
```

To get the grandparent directory of the batch file defined as an absolute path, *('one level up from where the batch file is')*, you'd use:

```bash
@For %%G In ("%~dp0..") Do @Set "GrandParent=%%~fG"
@Echo %GrandParent%
@Pause
```